# Leetcode out different than local running of the code

Tags: python

I am trying to get the working solution for: https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-k-sorted-lists/

And when I submit the solution, I notice that my code only concatenates the lists into a single list but doesn't sort it on the leetcode submission platform. But it works fine on my local laptop.

```
import heapq


# Definition for singly-linked list.
class ListNode(object):
    def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = next

    def __str__(self):
        return '{0} {1}'.format(self.val, self.next)

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.val < other.val


class Solution(object):
    def mergeKLists(self, lists):
        master = []
        res = None
        temp = None
        for i in range(len(lists)):
            if lists[i] is None:
                continue
            heapq.heappush(master, lists[i])
        while len(master) != 0:
            node = heapq.heappop(master)
            if node.next is not None:
                heapq.heappush(master, node.next)
            if res is None:
                res = node
                temp = node
            else:
                temp.next = node
                temp = temp.next
        return res


class LL:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None

    def add_node(self, val):
        nd = ListNode(val)
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = nd
            self.tail = nd
            return

        if self.head == self.tail:
            self.head.next = nd
            self.tail = nd
            return

        self.tail.next = nd
        self.tail = nd

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Head: {0}, Tail: {1}'.format(self.head, self.tail)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    l = [[3, 4, 5], [1, 3, 4], [5, 6]]

    linked_lists = []
    for lst in l:
        linked_list = LL()
        for i in lst:
            linked_list.add_node(i)
        linked_lists.append(linked_list.head)
    s = Solution()
    print(s.mergeKLists(linked_lists))
```

It would be great if someone can help with it.

Comment: I haven't tried running your code but I do notice that you're overriding *next*. It's rarely, if ever, a good idea to override Python built-ins

Comment: Would you prefer this one liner : `print(sorted(sum(l, [])))` ?

Comment: Where did you get your defn of `ListNode`.  Are you sure that the Leet `ListNode` provides a `__lt__` implementation.  I'm not sure I ever remember seeing that.  If you've created your own implementation of `ListNode`, that's great, but its not going to change the implementation of leet's list nodes.

Comment: @FrankYellin - I implemented it myself. Doesn't leetcode accept implementation of new class methods? I also felt that could be the difference.

Comment: Nope.  You can't.  The idea behind your algorithm is good, though.  It is unfortunate that heapq doesn't take a `:key` argument, but there are ways to work around that.